# wondering why this code is resulting in a syntax error?

Tags: python

Not sure why this code is resulting in a syntax error, anyone know why?

```
  # Ask for user input
    choice = input ("Enter the letter A or B: ")

    # Detect choice
    if choice == A:
        print ("You entered A!")
    elif choice == B:
        print ("You enetered B")
    else:
        print ("You didn't enter A or B!")
```

Comment: Where did you define variables called `A` and `B`? Did you mean to use literals `"A"` and `"B"` instead?

Comment: What you've shown doesn't have any syntax errors, except maybe around indentation. Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe This code can give syntax errors, or not. It all depends whether A and B are variable names, or meant to mean 'A' and 'B' instead. Most likely, the missing ' quotes are the problem

Comment: @GhostCat that wouldn't be a *Syntax*Error if they weren't defined, it would be a *Name*Error. Possibly the OP isn't using the term syntax error to mean an actual SyntaxError.

Comment: Please put A and B in strings or quotes 'A' , 'B'

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese kind-hearted in this case will be **not** to down-vote, but I get what you're saying. I mean, up-votes should be for well-asked questions. This is asking about an error and doesn't even bother to post the actual error...

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese it may be *nice* to upvote low quality questions, but it's certainly not *kind* - it's helpful neither for the OP, who doesn't get the signal they need that their current approach isn't acceptable, nor for all of the other users of the site, who rely on post scores to identify good content. Does this question show research effort? Is it useful? Is it clear?

Comment: @jonrsharpe lmao i'm not here to debate, was telling possible reasons

Comment: Thanks guys!, sorry i am very new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to tell him `if choice == A`. This means that A is a variable, and if A is not defined, it will not work ! You forgot to put 2 " to make it a string, and then to be able to compare it.
So now your code looks like:

```py
  # Ask for user input
    choice = input ("Enter the letter A or B: ")

    # Detect choice
    if choice == "A":
        print ("You entered A!")
    elif choice == "B":
        print ("You enetered B")
    else:
        print ("You didn't enter A or B!")
```

Answer (score 2):

As the input is stored as a string, you need to compare it with a string:

```
if choice == 'A':
    print ("You entered A!")
elif choice == 'B':
    print ("You enetered B")
else:
    print ("You didn't enter A or B!")
```

Comment: How would that raise a syntax error?

Comment: Maybe @Nathan52 said it was a syntax error not knowing it wasn't one, he didn't show us the error so it could not be a syntax one, and this seems to be the answer